# Edit Text is not showing while opening the soft keyboard in android

Tags: android

I have created an activity. It's working fine. But when i try to take input through the edit text. I am selecting the edit text, then the edit text gets hidden by the soft keyboard.

I have tried by giving the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` permission, but its not getting solved. please help me to resolve this issue guys.

Here is my screen when the activity is shown.

[image: initially looks like this]

And it shown like this when the edit text is selected.

[image]

You can see in the above image,the edit text is gets hidden, thats why i am unable to enter the text inside that. please help me resolve this.

This is my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOSoutletName"
        style="@style/HeadingTheme"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/transaction"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/outletname" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/black_dark" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOSBrand"
        style="@style/Head_Text"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="@string/brand"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerOSBrandName"
        style="@style/Style_Spinner"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@color/black_dark" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOScategory"
        style="@style/Head_Text"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="@string/category"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerOScategoryName"
        style="@style/Style_Spinner"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@color/black_dark" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOSProductNameHeading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/product_name"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/grey_default"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOSProductName"
            style="@style/ListViewHeaderThemeLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"                
            android:text="@string/product_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewseparator1"
            style="@style/ListViewHeaderSeperator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOSQuantity"
            style="@style/ListViewHeaderThemeLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/qty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewseparator2"
            style="@style/ListViewHeaderSeperator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOSPrice"
            style="@style/ListViewHeaderThemeLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/rp" />           
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
 <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewOS"
            style="@style/ListViewTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/footer_background_drawable"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        style="@style/horizontalImg"
        android:background="@color/black_dark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOSBack"
            style="@style/styleNormalButtonLargeLand"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left"
            android:text="@string/back" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOSSubmit"
            style="@style/styleNormalButtonLargeLand"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/discount1"
            android:text="@string/discount" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my layout for creating the list elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOSLProductName"
            style="@style/ListViewTextViewLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/product_name"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewselparator1"
            style="@style/ListViewTextSeperatorForAll" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextOSLQuantity"
            style="@style/ListViewTextViewLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#FBFCFE"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:text="qty"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black_dark" />
        <!-- android:background="#404040" -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewselparator2"
            style="@style/ListViewTextSeperatorForAll" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOSLPrice"
            style="@style/ListViewTextViewLarge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:text="rp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post xml of your layout

Comment: Try this. > Add scroll view to your parent layout.

Comment: I tried this also. not solved

Comment: `ListView` inside of `ScrollView` is not a best choise in such situation.

Comment: @Evos you are right. i dont want to go with the scrollview.coz its just showing only row of list

Comment: @Evos Added the layout file.please check and help me if you can

Comment: @nick where is listview in your xml?

Comment: Check you xml please, i can't find any `EditText` there

Comment: @sandy After completing with the HorizontalView. List view is added therer

Comment: Edit text is the list element if custom layout element. added another layout which containing the List elements

Comment: please see the edited question. added the list element layout there.

Comment: Try to set `android:minHeight = "50dp"` atribute for you `ListView` OR for it's parent layout.

Comment: Sorry Its not getting solved mate.

Comment: ok, one more try: set much bigger `minHeight` attribute,for example,`400dp` for `LineareLayout` that contain `HotizontalScrollView` and `LenearLayout` with you `ListView`, so it meens for parent of parent AND/OR for elements from previous comment EDIT: also remove any additional tags from manifest

Comment: Sorry its not working mate. can you please upvote my question so that others also can show there interest to resolve this issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20684/discussion-between-evos-and-nick)

Comment: this question is still in the running state. So please if anyone know the solution then please let me know

Answer (score 5):

Inside your Android manifest file, you had to set this tag in your desired activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

And Let me know if it works

Comment: this is already answered and also mentioned in my question. please read the question mate

Comment: He and i posted answer almost at same time

Comment: Work like a charm for me...+1

Comment: ok but. this is not the solution of my question. this is already mentioned in the question. please find the specific solution of this

Comment: Which edittext is hidden..Adjust pan allow content to scrollable so that you can give input to all input box

Comment: @nick.. i request to vote me up so that i can participate here on SO

Comment: can you please upvote my question to make others interest in this??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20685/discussion-between-nick-and-coder)

Answer (score 2):

Try **ScrollView** add `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: Its showing only one row of the list. not feasible by the user prospective.please say another way to achive the proper solution

Comment: on  alternative use layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: and One more thing add Gravity to your List View also center

Answer (score 0):

This is an Android issue (see link below) and happens in fullscreen, i.e. when there is no statusbar. Try your app in non-fullscreen.

Android issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10510

Edit: Fullscreen flags - you should remove these if you have them.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // removes title
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // removes statusbar
```

Comment: That issue is with the WebView + Fullscreen + Keyboard right. How it belongs to my question here??

Comment: Well, it is not just with webview, although it was reproduced with it. What you are doing right now is basically reproducing it again with a different view. Try removing fullscreen flag in your app and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this.I am not getting it properly. Can you please edit your answer

Comment: Normally the activity is not fullscreen and you add flags to make it fullscreen. If your app is fullscreen that means you have them. You should remove those flags (see the edit in my answer).